# linearly independent and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, systems-of-equations

This question says a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$ where $a_{ij}$ are real numbers. I need to prove that $\det|A|=ad-bc\neq0 \iff $the columns are linearly independent.
Suppose we already know that A's columns are linearly independent iff the system of equations $Ax=0$ where $x=(x_1, x_2)'$ only has trivial solution, that is, $(x_1=0, x_2=0)$ is the only solution.
The following is my answer:
$  \begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{4}
      ax_1 &+ bx_2 &&= 0 \\
      cx_1 &+ dx_2 &&= 0
    \end{alignedat}
  \end{equation} $
implies $  \begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{4}
      adx_1 &+ bdx_2 &&= 0 \\
      bcx_1 &+ bdx_2 &&= 0
    \end{alignedat}
  \end{equation} $
Then substract the second equation from the first equation, we get $ x_1(ad-bc)=0$
$(\Rightarrow)$ The columns are linearly independent, so $x_1=x_2=0$ is the only solution. Therefore, (ad-bc) cannot be $0$, otherwise $x_1$ can be any number.
$(\Leftarrow)$ As $ad-bc\neq 0$, we know the only solution to the above equation is $x_1=0$, and hence $x_2=0$. Therefore, the columns are linear independent.
My tutor says the argument is not sufficient, but I can't understand. Could you see the problem?

Comment: $x_1(ad-bc)=0$ and $x_1 =0$ does not imply that $ab - bc \neq 0.$ You need some more argument to show that $ad-bc \neq 0.$ You can start with the assumption that $ad-bc=0$ and try to show that there is a non-trivial solution of the equation $Ax=0.$

Comment: This is really not clear: first, where you wrote "implies" you should tell what **exactly** you're doing: multiplying first eq. by $\;d\;$ , 2nd one by $\;b\;$ . Second, when you say "substract the second...", do you mean the equations *after* they were multiplied? Yes, of course you do: say that explicitly. Finally, the case "($\implies$)" is wrong: that the only solution is $\;x_1=x_2=0\;$ does **not** imply, *at all*, that $\;0=x_1(ad-bc)=0\cdot(ad-bc)\implies ad-bc\neq 0\;$ . They both could be zero, say...why not? The case "($\Leftarrow$)" is way easier and correct.

Comment: to Krish. $x_1(ad-bc)=0$ and $x_1=0$ does not imply that $ad-bc\neq0$. This is true, but one more thing is that $x_1=0$ is the only solution, so I made this argument.

Comment: @bill As you wrote it, it is not enough. What you meant is other thing.

Comment: This seems the core problem: we know $x_1(ad-bc)=0$ and $x_1$ can only be $0$. Can we conclude that $(ad-bc)$ not be zero ?  
In my oppinion, if $ad-bc = 0$, then $x_1$ can be any number.

Comment: There is a small point of confusion. $x_1=x_2=0$ is the only solution of $Ax=0.$ That doesn't imply immediately that $ad-bc \neq 0$ from $x_1(ad-bc)=0.$ At the end this is the case of course. But that requires some argument. Like what will happen if $ad-bc=0.$ I think that's what your tutor meant. See the comment and answer by @Timbuc.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out.But I can't come out what is the essential thing to make it insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

After you see (hopefully) where you went wrong, I propose the following:

$$\binom ac\;,\;\;\binom bd\;\;\text{linearly dependent}\;\iff\;\exists\;k\in\Bbb R\;\;s.t. \binom bd=k\binom ac\iff$$

$$\binom bd=\binom{ak}{ck}\iff \det A=\begin{vmatrix}a&ak\\c&ck\end{vmatrix}=k\begin{vmatrix}a&a\\c&c\end{vmatrix}=k\cdot 0=0$$

and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But now my problem is: we already know that $x_1$ can only be $0$ and $x_1(ad-bc)=0$. Can we conclude that $(ad-bc)\neq0 $ ? 
Could you please explain why we cannot make such conclusion?

Comment: @bill I can't see how to properly present a proof *the way you tried* in "($\Rightarrow$)". In fact, using a square matrix is of full rank iff the associated homogeneous linear system has *only* the trivial solution seems to be a rather messy way to go, to say the least. This could work, imo, if we add some geometrical insight, say: the columns are lin. ind. $\implies$ the straight lines in the plane described by $\;ax+by=0\,,\,\,cx+dy=0\;$ are non-parallel ones (why?) $\implies$ the lines do not coincide and thus *obviously* only meet at one single point which, obviously again, is the origin.